# query SQL select from many tables by id?

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my sql query:

```
    function show($conn){


        $ask="  SELECT  people.per_id, people.per_name , people.hos_id,

        people.car_id, people.us_id FROM people

        inner join house  on house.hos_id = house.hos_id

        inner join car  on people.car_id =  car.car_id

        inner join user  on people.us_id = user.us_id  ";

    $query = $conn->prepare($ask);

    $query->execute();


        return $query;
    }
```

example of what the query shows

```
 people.per_id = 1
 people.per_name = mark
 people.hos_id = 3
 people.car_id = 5
 people.us_id = 7
```

what I want to see

```
people.per_id = 1
people.per_name = mark
people.hos_id = green house
people.car_id = suv 
people.us_id = faster
```

How can I access by id to another data from the tables house, car and user?

Comment: Where do you find those values suv, faster etc?

Answer (score 1):

try this

use `house.house_name` instead of `people.hos_id`, `car.car_name, user.user_name` and write `people.hos_id = house.hos_id` instead of `house.hos_id = house.hos_id`

```
function show($conn){

    $ask="  SELECT  people.per_id, people.per_name , house.house_name,
    car.car_name, user.user_name FROM people
    inner join house  on people.hos_id = house.hos_id
    inner join car  on people.car_id =  car.car_id
    inner join user  on people.us_id = user.us_id  ";

    $query = $conn->prepare($ask);
    $query->execute();
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -
You need to selct name from other tables like `house.name,car.name, user.name`
instead of `ids` columns

```
SELECT  people.per_id, people.per_name , house.name,car.name, user.name FROM people
inner join house  on people.hos_id = house.hos_id
inner join car  on people.car_id =  car.car_id
inner join user  on people.us_id = user.us_id
```